# Cancel drag on esc button

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I have a list control with enabled dragging in it. How could I cancel dragging by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no default behavior for cancelling of dragging, but you can listen for keyboard and simulate the mouse up event. Here is example (The solution is taken from [here](http://meamit.wordpress.com/2011/08/30/cancelling-drag-drop-operation-when-user-hits-escape/)):

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               keyDown="onKeyDown(event)">

        <s:List  dataProvider="{dataProvider}"  dragEnabled="true" />

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.managers.DragManager;
            import mx.managers.dragClasses.DragProxy;

            [Bindable]
            public var dataProvider:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([{label: "name1"}, {label: "name2"}, {label: "name3"}, {label: "name4"}]);

            private function onKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void
            {
                if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.ESCAPE)
                {
                    DragManager.acceptDragDrop(null);

                    // get drag proxy
                    var dragProxy: DragProxy = DragManager.mx_internal::dragProxy;
                    if (dragProxy != null) {
                        //provide some thing for mouse up
                        dragProxy.mouseUpHandler(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP));
                    }
                }
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
</s:Application>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've found this solution before, but don't know which libs should I import so I cant make it work.

Comment: May be you know, how could I hide the line which showing the position on which item will be inserted? This line stays visible even before draggable item disappeared.

Comment: Try `list.layout.dropIndicator.visible = false;`